# cant get the data what i expecting

Tags: php, odbc

**i am using PHP and SQL-SERVER.. my connection string is ok but when i try to fetch something let's say(a column) and when i `print_r()` it returns just column name and in data,it shows symbols. also i generate the JSON output with null values i am using the

following php script**

**my Connection File**

```
<?php
    class odbcConnection
{
    public $myServer = "SMS-HP\MSSQL";
    public $myUser = "sa";
    public $myPass = "123456";
    public $myDB = "procurementdb";
    public $connDB;

    // function to connection to the database 
    public function connectionDB(){

        // check wheather the given function exists 
        if(function_exists(odbc_connect))
        {

            $this->connDB = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$this->myServer;Database=$this->myDB;", $this->myUser, $this->myPass);
            //echo("Connection Established <br>");
        }
        else
        {
            die("Connection Failed".odbc_errormsg());
        }

    }

    // function to closing the connection
    public function closeConnection()
    {
        odbc_close($this->connDB);
    }

}//End of class

//$conn = new odbcConnection();
//$conn->connectionDB();

  ?>
```

**Load Storage Class File**

```
<?php
include("dbConnection.php");
class LoadStorageData extends odbcConnection
{
    public function LoadStorageData()
    {
        $this->connectionDB();
    }
    public function LoadData()
    {

        $sql ="select NameOfStorage from tblStaff where DivisionID=7 and DistrictID=1 order by NameOfStorage;";

        $result = odbc_exec($this->connDB,$sql);
        $dataSet = array();
        while($rows = odbc_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push($dataSet,$rows);
            echo("<pre>");
            print_r($rows);
            echo("</pre>");
        }

        if($dataSet){
            json_encode($dataSet);
            return json_encode($dataSet);
        }
        else{
            echo "error";
            return false;
        }

    }

}

$json = new LoadStorageData();
echo $json->LoadData();
$json->closeConnection();
```

?>

****output****

```
Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎý
)

Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎ
)

Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎýÎ
)

Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎýÎ
)

Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎýÎ
)

Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎýÎ
)

Array
(
    [NameOfStorage] => þÎýÎ
)

[{"NameOfStorage":null},{"NameOfStorage":null},{"NameOfStorage":null},{"NameOfStorage":null},{"NameOfStorage":null},{"NameOfStorage":null},{"NameOfStorage":null}]
```

**any help on this is appreciated ....

Thanks ....**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have binary data in "NameOfStorage" field, can you encode with base64_encode() function before pushing values in JSON and let see if data gets print in your array.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps using `mb_convert_encoding()` is useful. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)